# Automation tasks for system administrators

Tags: shell-script, python, perl

If I am a junior UNIX/Linux system administrator, and I want to make automation tasks for the server.

I know Shell script, Perl, and Python. All of these are used to make automation tasks.

Which one I can use to make the scripts?

Answer should be according to these conditions: 1. less lines of code. 2. high performance. 3. Portable source code, even I use KSH or BASH shell.

If there is no dedicated answer, so when I can use perl and when python and when shell-script?

Comment: Consider `perl` and `python` interchangeable. Shell is when you want to get something done quickly but performance is less of a concern.

Comment: You're concerned about the execution performance of a *shell script* (as opposed to whatever gets called by that shell script, which you likely have limited influence over anyway)? Just what are you *doing* in that shell script that makes *its* performance a concern?!

Answer (score 1):

If you want Perl, try `(R)?ex`: http://rexify.org/

If you want Python, try `fabric`: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/

Both can deploy with less line of code, better performance than shell. Try and make your choice.

I use both.

Comment: Python 2.5 disqualifies RHEL/CentOS 5. That's not very portable.

Comment: I know both of them, but my question about there is conditions prevent me to use one of them in some cases or not ?

Comment: No, I think it depends on your skill. If you are good at what, just use it for your work.